# Cant add Qwidget in pyqt5 gui when listening to firebase database stream

Tags: python, firebase, pyqt5

I am building a chat app using firebase and pyqt5. And I try to add Qlabel every time a new message is coming, but when I add the new label to the QVBoxLayout nothing  happened.
And I get this message:

> QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread

this my code:

```
class Window(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.init_ui()

    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
    self.db = firebase.database()
    self.my_name = 'Josh'

    self.message_streamer = self.db.child('messages').stream(self.message_listener)

def message_listener(self, data):
    try:
        sender = data['data']['sender']
        message = data['data']['message']
        if sender != self.my_name:
            self.add_message(f'{sender}: {message}')
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info())

def init_ui(self):
    self.main_vb = QVBoxLayout()

    self.scroll = QScrollArea()
    self.widget = QWidget()
    self.scroll_vb = QVBoxLayout()

    self.widget.setLayout(self.scroll_vb)

    self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

    self.text_box = QLineEdit()
    self.button = QPushButton()
    self.button.setText('send!')
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.send_click)

    self.main_vb.addWidget(self.scroll)
    self.main_vb.addWidget(self.text_box)
    self.main_vb.addWidget(self.button)

    self.setLayout(self.main_vb)
    self.setGeometry(600, 100, 700, 700)

def send_click(self):
    text = self.text_box.text()
    self.text_box.setText('')
    self.add_message(text)

    self.db.child('messages').push({'sender': self.my_name, 'message': text})

def add_message(self, message):
    self.scroll_vb.addWidget(QLabel(message))
    print(message)
```

here I listen to the changes

```
self.message_streamer = self.db.child('messages').stream(self.message_listener)

def message_listener(self, data):
    try:
        sender = data['data']['sender']
        message = data['data']['message']
        if sender != self.my_name:
            self.add_message(f'{sender}: {message}')
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info())
```

and here is where I am adding the new label an its not working
(When I call it from the push button its work )

```
    def add_message(self, message):
    self.scroll_vb.addWidget(QLabel(message))
    print(message)
```

Comment: The error message suggests that `message_listener` is being called on a separate (i.e. non-GUI) thread.  Creating `QWidget` instances on such threads is not supported.  If that is the underlying problem then you can use a queued signal/slot connection to achieve what you want.

Comment: please provide a [mre]